# Does the set of zeroes of $p(x)$ in $\mathbb{C}$ forms a group under multiplication? Yes/No

Tags: group-theory, polynomials

Is the following statement true or false:

> Consider the polynomial $p(x) = x^4 + 4$  in the  ring
> $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Then the set of zeroes of $p(x)$ in $\mathbb{C}$ forms a group under multiplication.

**My attempt:** Here $p(x) = x^4 + 4 = (x^2 + 2x + 2)(x^2 - 2x + 2)$.

I think this statement is true because zeroes of $p(x)$ are nonzero  so they have inverses. I mean that $\frac{1}{x}$ exists when $x$ is a zero of $p(x)$.

Comment: Do you know what the zeroes of $p$ are?

Comment: @Arthur yes  $x= 1-i , 1+i$

Comment: I think there are more than that.

Comment: yes , okay  @Arthur  $x= -1-i , -1+i$

Comment: Cool. Look at your four roots. Now look at your problem. Now look back at your roots. What does it take for them to make a group under multiplication?

Comment: For group  under multiplication,inverse  should  be exist @Arthur so i think  it is the necessary condition for example take  $x$  and  $x^{-1}$ both belong  to zeroes  of $p(x)$

Comment: Ok. Choose one of those roots. Now take its reciprocal. Do you still have a root?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141112/discussion-between-jasmine-and-arthur).

Comment: No, I don't like to chat. It creates an undue expectation to respond more quickly, and I don't get notifications when you respond. I willl choose to continue here.

Comment: okay  @Arthur no root...You  are correct

Comment: @Arthur that  mean  inverse don't exist .Am i right ?

Comment: Sounds right to me. There are slightly simpler ways to prove it, but that is one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Any root $\alpha$ of $p$ must satisfy $|\alpha|=\sqrt[4]{4}=\sqrt{2}$, and then $|\alpha^2|=2$ therefore $\alpha^2$ cannot be a root of $p$. So you don't need to compute what the roots really are.

Another way is to recognize the zeros are all in $\mathbb C^*$ which is a group, hence if the zeros form a group, it must be a subgroup of $\mathbb C^*$, but it doesn't contain the identity element of $(\mathbb C^*, \times)$ which is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that a multiplicative group must contain the identity element $1$; which unfortunately is not possible in your case as $p(1)=1^4+4=5\ne 0$.